# Highcharts-How to remove tooltip, one of data in series

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image]!
[image]

I drawing arrow using line

but I want to removed tooltip of second point.

to be exact, I want to show only one tooltip at a one arrow line

Is there any way??

Code:

```
$(function() {

  (function(H) {

    var arrowCheck = false,
        pathTag;

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {

      // Now apply the original function with the original arguments, 
      // which are sliced off this function's arguments
      proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

      var arrowLength = 15,
        arrowWidth = 9,
        series = this,
        data = series.data,
        len = data.length,
        segments = data,
        lastSeg = segments[segments.length - 1],
        path = [],
        lastPoint = null,
        nextLastPoint = null;

      if (lastSeg.y == 0) {
        lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
        nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
      } else {
        lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
        nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
      }

      var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
        (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY));

      if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle;

      path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

      if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {

        if (arrowCheck === true) {

          pathTag = document.getElementById("arrow");
          if (pathTag != null) {
            pathTag.remove(pathTag);
          }
        }

        path.push(
          'L',
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
        );
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
        );
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
          'Z'
        );
      } else {


        if (arrowCheck === true) {

          pathTag = document.getElementById("arrow");
          if (pathTag != null) {
            pathTag.remove(pathTag);
          }
        }

        path.push(
          'L',
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
        );
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
        );
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
          'Z'
        );
      }

      series.chart.renderer.path(path)
        .attr({
          fill: series.color,
          id: 'arrow'
        })
        .add(series.group);

       arrowCheck = true;

    });
  }(Highcharts));



  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      defaultSeriesType: 'scatter'
    },
    xAxis:{
        min: 0,
      max: 5
    },
    plotOptions: {

      series: {
        animation: {
          duration: 2000
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },

      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true,
          lineWidth: 2
        },

      }

    },

    series: [{
      name: 'main',
      id: 'main',
      data: [
        [0, 0],
        [3,4]
      ]
    }]
  });


});
```

Comment: code : http://jsfiddle.net/vyfsf1ft/3/

Comment: Define a point which you do not want to show in a tooltip with an additional property, e.g. showTooltip and set it to false. In the tooltip formatter you can check that property and depending on that - showing or not the tooltip - see example http://jsfiddle.net/vyfsf1ft/14/

Comment: @morganfree Thanks to you, I could solve the problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then update your series in accordance:

```
series: [{
  name: 'main',
  id: 'main',
  data: [
    {x: 0, y: 0],
    {x: 3, y: 4, tooltip: false}
  ]
}]
```

And update formatter configuration:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        if (this.tooltip) {
            return false;
        }
        // ... other stuff
    }
}
```

Or, instead of previous solution, it can be used pointer event:

```
series: [{
  name: 'main',
  id: 'main',
  data: [
    {x: 0, y: 0],
    {x: 3, y: 4, events: {mouseOver: function () {
        return false;
    }}}
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!, I could solve this problem.
I very happy.! Have a nice day! :)